# Sorting table by checked Checkboxes with tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter

I have a table with 3 columns. There is a checkbox in the second column. I need to sort the table according to the checked checkboxes, i.e. all the checked rows come first and all the unchecked follow. How can I do it?

```
function sort() {
  $('#container-table').tablesorter({
    debug:true,
    headers: {
      1: {
        sorter: 'checkbox'
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: It [works for me](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-grouping.html). Make sure to include the [`parser-input-select.js`file](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/parsers/parser-input-select.js) after the script that loads tablesorter. The sorter option (as above) should also be set.

Comment: can u please help me out with the options?